# How to retrieve elements from soap Payload in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: xpath, soap, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having below soap payload which comes from WSO2 DSS endpoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Response xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
         <RestrictionCount>
            <count>1</count>
         </RestrictionCount>
      </Response>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to extract **count** values from above payload. i tried like "//RestrictionCount/count/text()" by using [Online xpath expression tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) which gives me result, but in coding i tried the same by using property mediator expression like below which doesn't working for me

```
<property expression="//RestrictionCount/count/text()" name="count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Can anyone please help me into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dealing with namespaces, use `local-name()` to select the element :

```
<property expression="//*[local-name()='RestrictionCount']/*[local-name()='count']/text()" name="count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Or better, declare the namespace properly just before your XPath expression :

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" expression="//ns:RestrictionCount/ns:count/text()" name="count" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Hi @E.Wiest,

Thanks for your useful information. i have done this by  <property expression="//ns:count/text()" name="count" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
Another tried method:
<property expression="$body/*" name="RestrictionResponse" scope="default" type="OM"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:RestrictionResponse//*[local-name()='count']/text()" name="count"/>